# Animate image icon from touch place to right-top corner?

Tags: android, animation, viewanimator

I am working on Android onlineShopping application.I have to apply some animation.

1. cart image is displays on Right-top corner of the screen.
2. List of items are on screen each item with "Add to cart" button.
3. When user press this button I have to play animation.
4. I have one fix image which should animate from touch position to
   cart-image placed on right-top corner of the screen.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Update :

I Tried this to move image from one place to another.

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,200,200);              
                anim.setDuration(3000);

                img.startAnimation(anim);
```

This image I want to animate from touch position to right-top corner.
[image]

Comment: @ Indiandroid I have never work with animation. I just see a demo but not fullfills the requirement.

Comment: as you have mentioned you want to do animation from listview items to top right corner?if possible then add screen shot.

Comment: @ Indiandroid yup bro please help me out. Not able to figure out from animation demo code snippets.

Comment: @Indiandroid yes i will help but add image so that i can figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

ultimately you want to move a view from one position to another position with animation.

**Step 1:
get initial position of that view**

```
int fromLoc[] = new int[2];
v.getLocationOnScreen(fromLoc);     
float startX = fromLoc[0];
float startY = fromLoc[1];
```

**Step 2:
get destination position**

```
int toLoc[] = new int[2];
desti.getLocationOnScreen(toLoc);       
float destX = toLoc[0];
float destY = toLoc[1];
```

**Step 3: 
create a class to manage animation**

```
        public class Animations {
public Animation fromAtoB(float fromX, float fromY, float toX, float toY, AnimationListener l, int speed){


        Animation fromAtoB = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //from xType
                fromX, 
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //to xType
                toX, 
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //from yType 
                fromY, 
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, //to yType 
                toY
                 );

        fromAtoB.setDuration(speed);
        fromAtoB.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.0f));


        if(l != null)
            fromAtoB.setAnimationListener(l);               
                return fromAtoB;
    }
}
```

**Step 4:
add animationlistener and start animation on desired view**

```
     AnimationListener animL = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {     
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //this is just a method call you can create to delete the animated view or hide it until you need it again.
            clearAnimation();       
        }
    };
```

//now start animation as mentioned below:

```
Animations anim = new Animations();
    Animation a = anim.fromAtoB(startX, startY, destX, destY, animL,850);
    v.setAnimation(a);
    a.startNow();
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: thanks for nice answer sounds promising. Will try and update you what happens with me with this code.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you are exactly looking for, you can check link**

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085260/932219)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check this example hope this will help u:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html