# How to make animation for item when add to cart in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to translate and scale image from Recyclerview to cart button on top right corner.
I already try moving one image to another image but it's possible in same layout but what if I want to animate item that is inside Recyclerview and cart button out side Recyclerview.

I already tried demo form :
[Animate image icon from touch place to right-top corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534477/animate-image-icon-from-touch-place-to-right-top-corner)

But It's working on same layout only.

Ref. this video that is done in iOS.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Me0rDeOOkhw

Answer (score 2):

**You are looking exactly for this**
this can solve your problem

[Please check link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085260/932219)

[image]